# View past Gmail notifications?

Tags: gmail, notifications

The other day I logged onto Gmail I thought I saw a notification (the type that appears when you delete a convesation, etc) but I clicked away before I had a chance to read it.

Any chance I can go back and read past notifications?  I don't necessary want to (or expect to be able to) undo any actions, I just want to read them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notifications I think are real time and are discarded ASAP ( actualy ASAR, As soon as read). For more details and for the sake,
follow the link: http://mail.google.com/support/?hl=en

Comment: I suspect you're correct.